# Why is there no music by Elvis in Elvis & Nixon?

Tags: soundtrack, elvis-and-nixon

The movie [Elvis & Nixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_%26_Nixon) has quite a nice score, but does not feature any music by Elvis. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The licensing costs might be an issue, but it's more likely to be because of the required approval from **CKX Inc.**, *"the company that controls Presley's music, image and other intellectual property"*

The following quotes are from [this Hollywood Reporter article](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/race-make-an-elvis-movie-260272) from 2011 (emphasises are mine):

> (...) the famously tightfisted **CKX**, which
> acquired 85 percent of Elvis Presley Enterprises from Presley's
> daughter, Lisa Marie Presley, for $100 million in 2005, **must approve
> all uses**.
>
> (...) **CKX**'s fierce protectiveness of the Elvis image and the cost of licensing
> music, which can run into the **hundreds of thousands of dollars per
> track** (...)

Then, for *Elvis & Nixon* (which I haven't seen) add the fact that it portrays a "darker" part of Elvis' life and fictionalises some parts:

> The company (CKX) has a financial incentive to maintain **the image of an almost cartoonishly feel-good Presley** whom many fans remember, meaning it likely would not endorse a warts-and-all biopic.